# Check string in url and write html according

Tags: html

What language can be used to check a string or a link then write html accordingly? This is while a user loads the page. I need this so I can check the link if it .mp4 or .flv before I load the video player. If it has the included video format then it will load the code for the player if not it will display a message instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "if not it will display a message instead."

What is normally done in pure HTML is something like this:

```
<embed src="video.flv">
We're sorry, but your browser does not have the necessary plug-ins to display FLV video files.
</embed>
```

The error message is always there, but if the video actually loads then it is covered up.

Answer (score 2):

PHP, perl, python, asp, asp.net, and many other languages can be used. By far the most common server side language is PHP. It makes server-side coding relatively easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I know basic C which of this will I pick up easier? which is similar to C?

Comment: PHP has a c-like syntax. Python is meant to be an easy language to learn (although not at all similar to C). Perl is very hard to read (it uses many symbols for various purposes). ASP.NET can be a variety of languages (Visual Basic, C# (a very C-like language), and others). I suggest going with PHP for the similarity in syntax to C and the vast number of code samples and tutorials available for it online.

Comment: Great thanks for the information. I'll start reading up on PHP then.